# Is an AC/DC converter with no visible fuse before the transformer inherently dangerous?

Tags: power-supply, mains, safety, ac-dc

I've been using a generic, unregulated mains AC/DC converter (wall-wart) for a very low-power project.  It's output was a bit prone to 50 Hz ripple, so I opened it up to investigate how the circuit works, only to discover that there is no fuse between the mains live pin and the primary winding of the transformer.  Alarm bells started ringing in my head.

[image]

I'm inclined to hurl this thing unceremoniously into the electrical waste bin at a "recycling centre" (council tip), but is there any way this might still be a safe device?  It crossed my mind that the transformer *might* have a fuse inside it (wishful thinking?).  That would make this a disposable device I suppose, but if the manufacturer was cost-cutting then perhaps it's cheaper to use a transformer with an integrated fuse than have to engineer a user-replaceable one.

I notice that the primary side has an asymetric bulge on one side (see annotation).  Could that be a protection device?

But I'd like to know more about this construction.  Better safe than sorry.

---

**Edit**:
I've decided to sacrifice this old, questionable wall-wart in the name of science.

Yes, there was a thermal fuse wrapped up in the layers of insulation.

A 2 Amp fuse by the look of it, the ink had transferred from the fuse to the tape over the years!  Interesting stuff.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to be certain whether there is an internal fuse without transformer-surgery. || Advice I'm not recommending you follow :-). I'm 72, have too many decades of experience and have seen very very few transformer based supplies cause a fire. (I could say none, but maybe  very few long ago. Maybe not.) SO I'd not personally be too worried about a lack of fuse  as a gross secondary overload is liable to persuade the primary to go open circuit.  ||

Comment: if you are certain you don't want to use this device anymore, then there is an easy way to know if there is a fuse : just remove that yellow material (tape?) and check. But once you do, you will have to discard it whether there is a fuse or not.

Comment: I just found a youtube video about transistors with integral thermal fuses (rather than current fuses)... [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=4HoHERN_-DE).  Despite the poor video quality, the construction does look very similar (skip to 1 minute 30 seconds).

Comment: Bear in mind that the device is CE and FCC marked, so it must have met the regulatory safety requirements to be sold in the EU and US (assuming they didn't just put the marks on regardless). Also bear in mind that a fuse's primary purpose is to protect the cable leading to an appliance.

Comment: @Finbarr: AFAIK CE can be self certified, so it doesn't necessarily mean anything. And isn't FCC certification just for EMC?

Comment: *I'm inclined to hurl this thing unceremoniously into the garbage bin* - putting it in the electrical waste bin at a "recycling centre" (council tip) would be better.

Comment: You are so right.  Q improved immeasurably. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably fine.

There's normally no fuse as such in the old wallwarts with the big transformers like you have.

There's normally a fusible link inside the windings on the primary side.  The fusible link will break the circuit if the windings get too hot.  That protects against a short circuit, but also against simply running it at full power (or overloaded) for extended periods of time.

You can read more [about such transformers here.](https://josepheoff.github.io/assets/2020-04-05-howtosolder-16-new-soldering-iron/wp-ST-Class-vs-Class.pdf)

Comment: You're were right.  I've updated the Q with some exporative surgery.

Comment: @Wossname:  That's not simply a fuse.  A fuse blows when it gets hot from the current flowing through it.  The thing in your transformer will also blow when it gets hot from the windings around it.

Comment: I did say "thermal fuse".  Is that the wrong name? Sorry.

Comment: You were right.  I just didn't see the "thermal" in there.

Comment: I think you were right to question it though.  A thermal fuse could blow for either reason - over temperature, or over current right?  It did have "2A" on the package markings.  I guess that a momentary 2A load would cause it to reach its thermal limit very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

If it's supplied and manufactured by reputable people, it could use a safety isolation transformer and either not require a fuse or, have a fuse built into the primary winding.

Comment: interesting, what type of fuse would be used within a winding of an XFMR?

Comment: @RogerDodger:  It looks like a piece of wire.  It has a low melting temperature and just sort of fall apart when it gets too hot.

Comment: @JRE Oh fair point, I immediately was thinking of a discrete solution, something like littlefuse would sell but yes, I do know about using fusible links or even soldered connections as fuses. I also didn't read your answer :)